# Is the Square Root of a Real Number both positive and negative?

Tags: roots

Is the "Square Root of 4" equal to ±2 or 2? And the twist here is that if it is equal to ±2, then, what is "√4 + 2"? Is "√4 + 2" equal to just "4", or "4 and 0"? I am studying root right now and I just cant figure it out.

Comment: The convention is that if $x>0$ then $\sqrt x >0$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The square root of $a$, $\sqrt{a}$ where $a\geq 0$ is defined as the unique, **nonnegative** number which yields $\sqrt{a}\cdot\sqrt{a}=a$. The same goes for the $n$-th root of $a$.

If instead you are looking at a **quadratic equation** $x^2=4$, you are interested in all **solutions** to this equation. Here you get that not only $\sqrt{4}=2$ is a solution but also $-\sqrt{4}=-2$.

Comment: But `x^2 = 4` can be rewritten to be `x = square root of 4`. Then, it will no longer be a quadratic equation. What answer will this yield?

Comment: No, it can't be rewritten as just $x=\sqrt{4}$. Why should that be the case?

Comment: Then, what can it be rewritten to? Or is it not rewritable?

Comment: Those expressions arent equivalent, since square root is defined to be positive, @WhatsYourIdea

Comment: @WhatsYourIdea Rewrite as $x=\pm \sqrt 4$

Comment: Nonnegative, not positive, in the definition.

Comment: @DavidMitra you are absolutely right, I was going for $a>0$ first and then changed my mind. I will edit that as soon as I get back to a computer.

Comment: Both $2$ and $-2$ are square roots of $4$, but the *principal* square root, represented by $\sqrt{4}$, is $2$.